# Inventory or repository?

Tags: meaning

I have a program for managing products and intermediate artifacts stored in a human concrete building somewhere. The program is not only manage the artifacts existed, but also the resource planning for non-existed artifacts. So, what should I call this program, an *inventory manager*, or a *repository manager*, or *warehouse manager*, or something else?

Personally, I feel that *inventory* is not intuitive, it's prefixed with *invent-*, however, there are also purchased artifacts which are not invented by ourselves in the repository. Though, most people/documents call this piece of program as *inventory manager*.

Comment: What do you mean by a 'non-existed artifact'? Do you mean a virtual asset like a computer program, something which is purely imaginary, a product which is being designed but not yet produced or something else. The term 'non-existed artifact' is meaningless in English I'm afraid even if it is a literal translation of a term in another language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *repository* is a specific location where something is stored. A *warehouse* is a specific type of repository. An *inventory* is a list of stored objects. In other words, a *repository* is a concrete location (although nowadays, it's most commonly referred to in a programming context), a *warehouse* is also a concrete location (actually, a building), and an *inventory* is a more abstract idea.

When you're talking about a program that will list owned assets, you will want to go with the term *inventory manager*, because it's not a physical location.

Comment: Then, how about *asset manager* v. *inventory manager*?

Comment: @Ray *Asset manager* works in this situation.

Comment: A repository doesn't need to be physical; it only needs to store something (as opposed to an inventory, which only lists what's stored). For exampele, a repository of software packages is a virtual, digital, non-physical thing, and it's still a repository because it stores stuff.

Comment: Is a backpack considered a repository?

Answer (score 2):

A *warehouse manager* is more likely to be interpreted as the person in charge of running a warehouse.

A *repository manager* makes me think of a code repository, such as you might have in Subversion or Mercurial or some other source control system. The manager of a repository, whether human or heuristic, would have the job of dealing with that system.

An *inventory manager* makes me think of something that manages an *inventory* of products, which may, for example, be stored in a human concrete building somewhere. Therefore, I would go with that one.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. Inventory Manager fits the context. As a native English speaker, I do not automatically associate *"inventory"* with *"invent"* so there is no possible misunderstanding there :)